# can a virus cause programs to open on my computer?

Tags: virus

I had 18 viruses on my work computer and programs and even video games showed on my hard drive that I've never played sites I'd not looked at showing open all day?? Can a virus or maleware cause this?

Comment: I lost my job over it. Any way for me to prove that?

Comment: I am sorry about it man. Did you try to reproduce it ? I mean cleaning up your hard drive and getting the same result due to the malware effect. If yes then you have a point to prove. Unless it is pretty hard to prove it since a malware opening something from your computer is as same as you are opening it on your own. Same uac permission which it got from you during some of your software installation. Good luck.

Comment: Proving it is going to be difficult, since much malware runs in the same context as the logged-in user.  Your best hope would be to look for conflicting logs, such as any logs that show you on those web sites or starting those games when the office isn't even open.  This is likely to require the cooperation of the people who fired you, though.

Answer (score 3):

**Yes, it can**. Once it gets/bypasses the user account control.

When you are not careful enough while installing something then you might invite a malware inside. Once you have given permission (**User Account Control** permissions) to run a software that contains malware, then officially you are granting rights to it.

Now you opening a program or the malware opening a program wouldn't make much of a difference to the os since you both posses same rights.

It is quite easy for any malware to do whatever they want. So opening programs are just a child play for a malware. Imagine what will happen if a keylogger is installed and tracks all your keypress, gathers your sensitive information like bank account passwords and passing it outside. Horrible right? One solution could be doing a clean sweep with a good antivirus software and keeping it updated.

**Bottomline**: Always know what you are installing.

Comment: Even without administrative rights (which is what UAC is about) a program can do *a lot* (including installing arbitrary additional software and starting it) unless the PC is really locked down.